# Ubuntu installation Error 15 file not found

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, grub

For some reason the existing operating system (Fedora is giving kernel panic error) so I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS desktop version. When I boot from a bootable USB it just shows 2 options (no option for "Try Ubuntu Without installing"):

- Ubuntu without ACPI off
- Ubuntu with ACPI off

The main problem I'm facing is the error "Error 15 file not found".

Note:

1. I had tried it with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS desktop, it gave the same error. Here's the screenshot of the same:
   [image]
2. I can't access the existing OS.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer(s). I solved it today. It was finding grub4dos because I was booting in legacy mode. I changed the boot option to UEFI and used rufus to create a bootable USB.